# What would be the correct interpretation of "glimpses of the moon"?

Tags: interpretation

I read this in Hamlet:

> What may this mean,
>
> That thou, dead corpse, again in complete steel
>
> Revisit'st thus the **glimpses of the moon**...

I'm unable to figure out what the correct interpretation semantically of the bold part would be. Some sources like [this](https://genius.com/3978233) and [this](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/hamlet/act-1-scene-4) suggest that it means that the moon glimpses the earth, its light emanating from it to get a view of the earth (which I think shouldn't be considered a glimpse since the moon is there in the sky for at least 4-5 hrs generally, contrary to a typical "glimpse" duration). But other sources like [this](https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/hamlet/page_54/) suggest that the person has come back to look at the moon or glimpse the moon. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: This is not the right place for this question.  This is a question of literature interpretation and not about learning English. Try the Literature stack exchange.  You would probably benefit from sparksnotes if you need a modern gloss https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/hamlet/page_54/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" is explicitly listed as off-topic in the Help Center.